# Wordpress show posts by ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a litle stuck here, I want to get one or more posts just by their ID. What I've got now is:

```
<?php
$post_id = 1;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Though this shows my post without the breaks and looks I made in my backend. And I think this is kinda a long code for getting a single post.

So my question is, how can I get an post by ID to be shown in the most clean code with the breaks I put in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole point of get_post, I don't believe there is another way.